# Is there a way to view all two-dimensional arrays in matrix form?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, output-formatting

Is there a way to ensure that every time I perform an operation such as RowReduce, Linear Solve, Null Space, Inverse, Eigenvectors, etc. that the matrix is displaying in MatrixForm instead of applying the postfix form of MatrixForm every time (//MatrixForm)?
For example, is there a variable in the Option Inspector to set the default form of an array?
I checked but couldn't find anything of the sort.
If not, I am going to make a feature request for a future release of Mathematica.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html):

[image]

```
$PrePrint = If[MatrixQ @ #, MatrixForm @ #, #] &;

Array[x, {4, 5}]
```

[image]

```
{{a, b}, {x, y}}
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];
rm = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
N @ Eigenvectors[rm]
```

[image]

Comment: How do create a global matrix preprint setting? It reverts back after I close the kernel.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to teach [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) about your desired formatting:

```
Unprotect[StandardForm];
StandardForm /: MakeBoxes[l_List, StandardForm] /; MatrixQ @ Unevaluated @ l := MakeBoxes[MatrixForm[l]]
Protected[StandardForm];
```

Comment: Is this to be applied in a notebook or init.m?

Comment: That is up to you.

Comment: My init.m changes are undone after I restart. How do I make permanent modifications?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to automatically view two-dimensional arrays in matrix form using the Option Inspector to change from StandardForm to TraditionalForm.

1. Launch Mathematica.
2. On the Mathematica main menu, select Mathematica > Settings...
3. Click on the Advanced tab.
4. Click on the Open Option Inspector button.
5. In the Options column, open Cell Options > New Cell Defaults > CommonDefaultFormatTypes.
6. Within the CommonDefaultFormatTypes folder, find the word "Output." Click to the far left of the word "Output" (near the left edge of the dialog box in the Set column).
7. To the right of the word "Output", double-click on the words StandardForm and replace them with the words TraditionalForm
8. Press the enter key.
9. Close all open dialog boxes. This change should now be permanent in future sessions for the current user.

This procedure worked for me with Mathematica 13.1 and is a very slightly updated version of the following link.

https://support.ti.davidson.edu/hc/en-us/articles/115011833707-Display-Mathematica-Matrices-in-2D-Format

Comment: Please include the detailed procedure in your answer rather than relying on the link, which eventually will break.

Comment: Thanks.  Made the change you requested.