# How to change Global Preprint preferences for how matrixes are displayed?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, display, default

I asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258531/is-there-a-way-to-view-all-two-dimensional-arrays-in-matrix-form) about how to make all array outputs be displayed as matrices a few weeks ago. I have run into a problem ensuring that the setting change is permanent, however. I thought the global setting for PrePrint would be in the Option Inspector's Global Preferences, but I didn't find anything in it.
I also read the documentation for `$Preprint` but didn't find a way to change it.
I tried editing the init.m file but recieved this error on startup:
[image]
I opened init.m in Notepad++ and added this line:
$PrePrint = If[MatrixQ @ #, MatrixForm @ #, #] &;
How can I fix this error?

[image]
[image]
I tried editing the file init.m using Mathematica and it also returned an error.

[image]

Comment: Put your ``$PrePrint`` in the [``init.m``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't open ``init.m`` in Notepad. Open and edit it in Mathematica.

Comment: It didn't work in Mathematica. I will post a screenshot.

Comment: Looks like you added the line to the arguments of `SetOptions`: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ..., FontSize -> 20 $PrePrint = If[..]&;]`.  The expression `FontSize -> 20 $PrePrint = If[..]&;` when evaluated will generate a `Set::write` error, and the expression's value of `Null` is not a valid option. Move it outside `SetOptions`: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ..., FontSize -> 20]; $PrePrint = If[..]&;`. Personally I do not use init.m for reasons such as the problem you have run into. I keep a notebook with bits of init code I frequently want, and execute them by hand as needed.

Comment: I also tried moving it outside the SetOptions, but the changes reverted to the default display after I restarted Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a comma missing after `FontSize->20`?

Another option is to set `TraditionalForm` as the preferred output format: this automatically displays a matrix as a matrix.

Comment: I got it to work.

Comment: @Peter Burbery can you, please, explain how? What was wrong & how did you fix it to work? Thanks

Comment: I chatted with Wolfram support and edited a different init.m file